# Error during installation on Raspberry Pi with ROS Kinetic due to YAML

Tags: installation, yaml, ros

I'm installing ROS Kinetic on Raspberry Pi 3 b+ following this tutorial.
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

My software version of Raspbian is this.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/PDkqA5t4tihD6RV5A

When I try to install "map_server" I get this error.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/rq4LSG4zSKA8sTU36

And this is a video with the complete proccess.
https://youtu.be/WxnyF_9ugiw

I don't know how to solve the problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: The problem is that you compile C++11 code with a GCC that does not have C++11 support enabled via the `-std=c++11` switch (this is directly what the error message tells you). GCC defaults to C++14 support since GCC 6 so either the build script is manually disabling it or you have an ancient GCC. Try updating GCC.

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast. I have a problem them because for compiling ROS I think I need GCC 5. https://answers.ros.org/question/327497/compiling-ros-on-raspberry-pi-4-with-buster-problem-with-libboost158/

Comment: You could try explicitly using `gcc-6` instead of `gcc-5`, but the [release page for that libboost version you need](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_58_0.html) lists GCC 5.0.0 as newest „experimental“ version, so your chances are rather slim. Since the build system is CMake-based, you might find a way to inject the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` via command line (usually `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11 […]`). Did you read and understand the notes about libboost 1.58 in the tutorial you linked?